# Best selection algorithm for filtering a list with multiple criteria?

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm

I'm programming in Objective-C, but a language-agnostic answer would work fine here. I've got a list of objects with many attributes, including a date of creation and a user GUID. I'm looking for a reasonably efficient way to filter this list to include only the most recent entry from each user ID. Is there a solution better than O(n^2)? I think I could check each element, and if it's an ID I have not yet processed, grab all the objects with the same ID, find the most recent, and store that value elsewhere, but this seems like a naive approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to beat O(n^2) then you can sort by (ID, time) and then iterate through and the first time you see the ID, append it to some answer list. This will be O(n log n).

Alternatively, create a Hash table and iterate through the list. Check if the item is in the map (by ID), if it is then replace it with the current if it is less-recent. For a perfect hash function this would be O(n).

Comment: Thanks! I'll do the latter, I think.